# c command line int is wrong

Tags: c, int, command-line-arguments

Whenever I send in a number from the command line it errors and gives me a wrong number

```
edgeWidth=*argv[2];
printf("Border of %d pixels\n", edgeWidth);
fileLocation=3;
```

`./hw3 -e 100 baboon.ascii.pgm` is what I send in through the command line and when I print the number to the screen I get 49 as the number

`int edgeWidth` is defined at the beginning of the program.

Why is it not giving me 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by doing

```
edgeWidth = *argv[2];
```

you're assigning the first character of `"100"` to edgeWidth. 49 happens to be the ASCII value for `'1'`.

If you want `100`, you need to use something like `atoi` or `strtol` to parse the string into an int.

---

Addendum: Regarding numeric promotion, part two of 6.5.16.1 in the [C99 spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) states:

> In *simple assignment* (=), the value of the right operand is converted
>   to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored
>   in the object designated by the left operand.

so it does appear that numeric promotion happens here.

Comment: OK, I had a feeling that was the problem. Thank you it worked! Much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

`argv` contains an array of strings. So `argv[1]` is a string, you need to convert it to an integer:

```
edgeWidth = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because command line arguments are by default as `char*` (or may be `char**` somewhere) not `int`. you need proper conversion like `atoi()` to use it as `int`.
You should use `edgeWidth = atoi(argv[2])` to get expected output.

Comment: Wrong - use `atoi(argv[2])` not `atoi(*argv[2])`. You would end up looking at a character instead of a string. I don't think the compiler would let you...